# Setting substitution fonts in AcroForm itext7

Tags: java, unicode, itext7

I have a pdf with AcroForm and need to fill it with string that contains different languages glyphs (English, Chinese, Korean, Khmer).
In iText5 I've used:

```
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.addSubstitutionFont(arialFont);
form.addSubstitutionFont(khmerFont);
```

And it worked fine for Chinese and Korean, but I've faced an issue with Khmer ligatures not being rendered. Found out that I need pdfCalligraph addon to make ligatures work, but it comes with iText7 only. I've managed to add paragraphs with proper Khmer ligatures rendering (requiring typography as a dependency and loading a license key). But in AcroForm it won't do it automatically. I'm struggling to find an iText7 version of `addSubstitutionFont` and make it work with pdfCalligraph.

Code I've used with iText7:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templatePath);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(outputPath));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
PdfFont khmerFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(pathToKhmerFont, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(pathToArialUnicodeFont, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);

pdf.addFont(khmerFont);
pdf.addFont(font);

FontSet set = new FontSet();
set.addFont(pathToKhmerFont);
set.addFont(pathToArialUnicodeFont);
document.setFontProvider(new FontProvider(set));
document.setProperty(Property.FONT, "Arial");

form.setNeedAppearances(true);

String content = "khmer ថ្ងៃឈប់សម្រាក and chinese 假日 and korean 휴일";
PdfFormField tf = form.getField("Text3");

tf.setValue(content);

// tf.setFont(khmerFont);
tf.regenerateField();
// add a paragraph just to check pdfCalligraph works
document.add(new Paragraph(content));
pdf.close();
```

String used to test proper rendering: "khmer ថ្ងៃឈប់សម្រាក and chinese 假日 and korean 휴일"

iText5 in form field without pdfCalligraph, but with substitution fonts:
[image: iText5 without pdfCalligraph]

iText7 in form field with pdfCalligraph loaded (set arial font `field.setFont(arialFont)`):
[image]

iText7 in form field with pdfCalligraph loaded (set  khmer font `field.setFont(khmerFont)`):

[image]

iText7 same document but in a paragraph instead of form field with pdfCalligraph loaded (It is an expected resut, so it does use pdfCalligraph for paragraphs, but not for form fields):
[image]

So, as you can see there're basically 2 issues:

1. How do I `addSubstitutionFont` in iText7?
2. How do I use pdfCalligraph in PdfFormField appearance?

I've also checked if pdfCalligraph works in text form and it looks like it does not. Here is a code I've used to check it:

```
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(path_to_license);
String outputPath = path_to_output_doc;
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputPath));
Document document = new Document(pdf);

// prepare fonts for pdfCalligraph to use
FontSet set = new FontSet();
set.addFont("/path_to/Khmer.ttf");
set.addFont("/path_to/ArialUnicodeMS.ttf");
FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider(set);
document.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
document.setProperty(Property.FONT, "Arial");

String content = "khmer ថ្ងៃឈប់សម្រាក and chinese 假日 and korean 휴일";
// Add a paragraph to check if pdfCalligraph works
document.add(new Paragraph(content));
// Add a form text field
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
PdfTextFormField field = PdfFormField.createText(pdf, new Rectangle(36, 700, 400, 30), "test");
field.setValue(content);
form.addField(field);
document.close();
```

Output with pdfCalligraph dependency loaded (as you can see paragraph rendered properly, but in form all non-halvetica chars just ignored:
[image]

Output without pdfCalligraph dependency loaded (as you can see paragraph is not rendered properly which is expected, the form field looks same as with loaded pdfCalligraph):

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually pdfCalligraph should work in form fields without any modifications if it's on classpath, so you should double check it. Regarding the substitution fonts, it's not supported at the moment, and bear in mind that if you modify the field value in any viewer afterwards, you won't be able to edit the multilanguage string properly.

Comment: @AlexeySubach thanks for response, but I've double checked  and it looks like pdfCalligraph ignores text form field. I will add the code I've used to the question itself.

Comment: Ah, there is one thing you should do to make it work - set the font for the field with `setFont` method. So one font per field + pdfCalligraph will work, but many fonts per field are not supported at the moment.

Comment: @AlexeySubach thanks for explanation, yeah, just tried to set a khmer font for a field and remove all non-khmer chars and pdfCalligraph did work, unfortunately it does not  solve the issue, unless there is a way to get a "most satisfying font" for a string in iText7. Maybe you know there's a class that allows me to get the most satisfying PdfFont from the font set for the passed string? Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: No, not directly. You can implement this by yourself, though. First, create a glyphline from Unicode string by calling `PdfFont#createGlyphLine()`, then explore the result with `toString()` or other available methods.

Comment: @AlexeySubach thanks :)  Any ideas if and when multiple font pdfCalligraph in form field might be implemented/supported?

Comment: This is definitely not a priority because as I said the use-case is questionable due to inability of editing such fields in PDF viewer applications, so it will all depend on customers requesting this functionality.